# I keep receiving Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method error during function call

Tags: javascript

I created a function that would do something unique on it's 3rd call. In this case, alert the incremented number. However, when trying to call this function from another function:
"MyFunction();", I get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'MyFunction'. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var counter = 0;
var num = 0;

function = MyFunction() {
// increment outside counter
counter++;
if (counter === 3) {
    // do something every third time
    num++;
    alert('the new number is: ' + num);
    // reset counter
    counter = 0;
 }
}
```

I've also tried removing the = sign, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/6/ it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dacaxaqe/1/edit)

Just remove the `=` sign  `function MyFunction() {` and make sure in your fiddle that JS `<script>` is in the right place<sup>See additional explanation below</sup>.

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('button');
var counter = 0;
var num = 0;

function MyFunction() {
   counter = ++counter % 3; // loop count
   if ( !counter ) {
      num++;
      alert('the new number is: ' + num);
   }
}


//On click:
element.addEventListener('click', MyFunction, false);
```

your new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/7
The old one of yours was not working cause you did not used `No Wrap - in body` for the JS in your fiddle. (See options panel at the left up corner)

So basically you need to put your `<script>` tags before your `</body>` closing tag in order to make sure the DOM is ready and parsed by JavaScript before elements manipulation.

Comment: @Brandon added a demo

Comment: @Brandon your new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/7/ The old one of yours was not working cause you did not *No Wrap - in body* the JS in your fiddle. (see options panel at the left up corner)

Comment: Right, thanks. I've seen that and now it works however it still doesn't work in my project. I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'MyFunction'. in the console.

Comment: @Brandon that probably means you did not removed the `=` or you're using your `MyFunction` out of scope.

Comment: @Brandon expanded my comment above. Was that helpful? You function needs to be defined outside other functions in order to be accessible to other functions.

Comment: @Brandon if the above souded like Klingonian to you  `;)` here's an example: http://jsbin.com/gaposoqi/1/edit Happy coding

Comment: Nope, it was helpful, and I feel stupid now :) Actually my above example was hypothetical. My actual code is where my problem lies but I got confused and thought it had to do with the function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var MyFunction=function () {
    // increment outside counter
    counter++;
    if (counter === 3) {
        // do something every third time
        num++;
        alert('the new number is: ' + num);
        // reset counter
        counter = 0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntacs looks wrong to me, try

var foo = Myfuntion();
or
var foo = new MyFuntion();

depending on what MyFuntion() is.